# SyntaxError while trying to run python code (Array)

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting an error:

```
File "/home/ofw/playlister/app.py", line 7
    playlists = [
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
playlists = [
    { 'title': 'Cat Videos', 'description': 'Cats acting weird' },
    { 'title': '80\'s Music', 'description': 'Don\'t stop believing!' }
]

@app.route('/)
def playlists_index():
    """Show all playlists."""
    return render_template('playlists_index.html', playlists=playlists)
```

I'm guessing it's related to the playlist array. Any suggestions? In advance, thanks.

Comment: second `app.route` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the positioning of your playlist variable is wrong, because it's directly under a decorator "@app.route" What SHOULD come after a decorator is a function. try editing the code this way:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/)
def playlists_index():
    """Show all playlists."""
    playlists = [
    { 'title': 'Cat Videos', 'description': 'Cats acting weird' },
    { 'title': '80\'s Music', 'description': 'Don\'t stop believing!' }
    ]

    return render_template('playlists_index.html', playlists=playlists)
```

or creating the playlist variable globally, this way:

```
playlists = [
    { 'title': 'Cat Videos', 'description': 'Cats acting weird' },
    { 'title': '80\'s Music', 'description': 'Don\'t stop believing!' }
    ]
@app.route('/')
def playlists_index():
    """Show all playlists."""
    return render_template('playlists_index.html', playlists=playlists)
```

don't forget to correct your route string on line 11 to:

```
@app.route('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a decorator on line 5 but there is nothing to decorate below. There must be a function/method.
The one on line 11 is correct.